# NEST Wait for the server to finish indexing after bulk insert

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm indexing a number of documents using Nest 7.0:

```cs
await client.IndexManyAsync(docs, myAlias, cancellationToken);
```

For my tests I need to make sure I can query the indexed documents with 100% guarantee because wait for a fixed amount of time after `IndexManyAsync()` doesn't always work. I think I need an equivalent of `?refresh=wait_for` parameter but cannot find any examples in the fluent API and `IndexManyAsync()` doesn't have any suitable overloads :( How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling index refresh after `IndexManyAsync` will do the job

```
await elasticClient.Indices.RefreshAsync("index_name");
```